# Docker: Start Tomcat after running Oracle and scripts executed

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, docker

I am really new to Docker and enjoy it, however, I found some problems with running my application. I want to run my application which consists of 2 services:

1. I would like to start Oracle and run some DDL and DATA scripts which should take above 30 seconds
2. I would like to start Tomcat and launch my war file after the first step is finished as it won't start without it.

I've already read about: [docker-wait](https://github.com/aanand/docker-wait) and this is not what am i exactly waiting for as I should execute some scripts after my db would be available on specified port.

As I understand, the right way to start multiservises application is to use `docker compose`.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` for now:

```
version: '2'
services:
web:
build: Server
ports:
 - "8080:8080"
depends_on:
 - oracle
oracle:
build: Oracle
ports:
 - "1521:1521"
```

depends_on just lets me to order start of apps and nothing more.

For both Tomcat and Oracle I am using most popular images from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/).

How could I get the right way to start Tomcat after Oracle has started and scripts are executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`depends_on` only checks that the container is running, not that the service inside it is ready to accept requests. What you want is for your `web` service to start only when your `oracle` service is ready. You can use a script like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to do this. Eg:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: Server
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - oracle
    command: wait-for-it.sh oracle:1521 --timeout=8 -s -q -- myservercmd
  oracle:
    build: Oracle
    ports:
    - "1521:1521"
```

Comment: where should i put wait-for-it.sh?

Comment: In your Dockerfile use `COPY wait-for-it.sh /usr/local/bin/`.